# How can I capture user's last login and display the next time they login to the website in XPages?

Tags: authentication, xpages, xpages-extlib

I am working on developing a custom user portal using XPages. I would like to capture a user's last login/signin information and display it on the portal when the user logs in on the banner page.

Does anyone know how I can accomplish this for an XPages app?

Any help or insight into this is greatly appreciated.

Thank you!
Shabana.
My Portal Link: http://bit.ly/OJmanJ

Answer (score 2):

I do this with a User document and just save the information of the last login there. Then I set a flag in sessionScope to know that I saved it already.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this information is logged automatically anywhere. So you need to log it yourself and then display this logged information on your portal.